# Получить большую фотографию с профиля vk.com не через javascript

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Возможно ли как-то получить большую фотографию с профиля не через javascript?
Например в фейсбуке можно так:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture?type=large
```

есть ли аналогичный способ для котакта? просто нужно записать в базу адрес к фотографии а с джавой не особо дружу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX и API Контакта в помощь
Типо того:

```
  <script src="http://vkontakte.ru/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ....
      var data = {
        parent_id: myVK.options.id,
        vk_id: myVK.user.uid,
        name: myVK.user.first_name+' '+myVK.user.last_name,
        foto: myVK.user.photo_rec
      };

      $.ajax({
       url: '/new.php',
       data: data,
       type: 'POST',
       cache: false,
       success: function(answ) {
        alert(answ);
       },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$graph_url = "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?access_token=ТОКЕН&uids=IDЮЗЕРА&fields=first_name,last_name,country,city,photo_medium,photo_big,bdate,photo_rec,about,screen_name,contacts";
$params = file_get_contents($graph_url);
$param = json_decode($params);
$trumb = $param->response[0]->photo_medium; // фотка малая 100 на 100
$photo = $param->response[0]->photo_big; // фотка
```

Comment: @Mons, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.